# Hive UDF that uses Hive table

Tags: java, hive, user-defined-functions

I have developed a hive udf in java that works correctly, my function return the best match between the input and a column in a hive table, so it have this simplified pseudo-code:

```
class myudf  extends udf{

    evaluate(Text input){

        getNewHiveConnection(); //i want to replace this by getCurrentHiveUserConnetion();
        executeHiveQuery(input);
        return something;
}
```

My question is, if this function is invoked by Hive, why i need to connect to hive in my code ? can i use the current connection that the user who use my function is connected by ?

Comment: @54I3d Did you get any luck ?

Comment: @Giri I went with an alternative solution, i included the table data into the jar file, as a properties file. It work so fast as the file is too small, but i need to update the jar when the table is updated !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a closest match from entire column in a query, you could think if it as some sort of aggregation and use Hive UDAF:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GenericUDAFCaseStudy

There's also quite handy tutorial:
http://beekeeperdata.com/posts/hadoop/2015/08/17/hive-udaf-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way will be to create Macros. They work both on Hive and Beeline.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO fn_maskNull(input decimal(25,3))
CASE
    WHEN input IS NULL THEN 0 else input
END;

-- usage
select fn_maskNull(null), fn_maskNull(101);
```

More info :

https://medium.com/@gchandra/create-user-defined-functions-in-hive-beeline-ff965285d735

Comment: It need it in java coz it implement a complicated logic, the question was simplified to focus on the solution. Thx !

Answer (score -3):

Yes - you can make the UDF permanent. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MatchFinder as 'com.mycompany.packagex.myudf' using jar  'hdfs:///an_HDFS_directory/my_jar_name.jar';
```

This will make your function permanent and anyone will be able to call it. In this case, the jar file is stored on HDFS for easy accessibility, but there are other options.

See [Hive wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/ReloadFunction) for more details.

Comment: This is not what im looking for, i want to use the current connection used by the user who invoke my udf, instead of creating new connection, just to make it faster.